# How to make current element become previous element in a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to make a 1v1 card game where the player and computer take turns putting down 1 poker card per turn. In the first turn, the first card that is played will be the first current card. In the second turn, the current card in the previous turn becomes the new previous card and there is a new current card played. How do I do this?

My code below does not do this but instead assigns a completely new previousCard and currentCard for each loop.

```
while (playerDeck.length > 0 && computerDeck.length > 0) {
  currentCard = playerDeck.pop();
  nextCard = computerDeck.pop();
  previousCard = currentCard;
  currentCard = nextCard;
  console.log(previousCard, currentCard);
}
```

Here is the setup for my playerDeck and computerDeck:

```
class Card {
  constructor(value, suit) {
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
  }
}

const VALUES = [
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "10",
  "J",
  "Q",
  "K",
  "A",
];
const SUITS = ["♠", "♥", "♦", "♣"];

const createDeck = () => {
  const deck = [];
  for (const suit of SUITS) {
    for (const value of VALUES) {
      const card = new Card(value, suit);
      deck.push(card);
    }
  }
  return deck;
};

const deck = createDeck();
const shuffledDeck = shuffleDeck(deck);
playerDeck = shuffledDeck.slice(0, Math.floor(deck.length / 2));
computerDeck = shuffledDeck.slice(Math.floor(deck.length / 2), deck.length);
```

Comment: I don't think that there is enough information to answer this question. Can you clarify some more information about the player deck object?

Comment: You could add the new cards to an array and save you creating those variables. You're not doing anything with them, for example.

Comment: @Andy I am planning to display the currentCard and previousCard with html and css in a game so I need them to be variables with values. I am not planning to display the nextCard but included it because I thought it might be needed for reassigning values to variables.